# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" while writing discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to create a bot which can relay messages from a host server to every other server the bot has been invited to. I have had a nudge in the right direction with someone giving me this code to work with.

```
const channels = ['broadcast', 'start'];
 let announcement = args.slice(1).join(' ');
bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
let channel = guild.channels.cache.first();
 channels.forEach(c => {
  const ch = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === c);
  ch.send(announcement);
```

Unfortunately the console responds with an error, saying that either `send is undefined` or that `ch.send is not a real function`. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong ? I am still fairly new to coding.

Edit: Here is the type error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Update: Thanks for the help guys im closer to a solution now. I reached this error now tho

```
C:\Users\profile\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:160
            if (fn(val, key, this))
                ^

TypeError: fn is not a function
```

Comment: Please don't speak in approximations. Copy-paste the *exact* error you're getting into the question. Saying "I get an error" doesn't help. Showing us the error text can often zero in on the precise problem, and as a bonus others with the same error can search and find this question if it gets answered.

Comment: This is some really confusing code, what are you trying to do? Send a message to the first channel of every guild? The error is probably that you are trying to call `.send` on either a voice channel or a category. Another possible error is that you are reusing variables.

Comment: got it, ill re-edit and make it more specific.

Comment: Seems reasonably straight forward... `message.guild.channels.cache` does not contain channels named _broadcast_ or _start_ (possibly one or both)

Comment: Don't add that as comment, edit your post (and delete the comment). Also, errors are not "one line", where is the stack trace that shows where in _your_ code things go wrong? Because right now you're only showing one line, about code in discord's own library, which is absolutely not where the error will be: it'll be in _your_ code that ends up falling through to the line you're showing. So at this point, it's time to consider following the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and post a [mcve] instead of only a few lines of unconnected code.

Comment: alright ill read that

Comment: I am truly sorry if I come off a bit naive. This is my first major project and I am not as experienced as all of you are. I will try my best to make sense in what im asking,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help but turns out, I was greatly overthinking this. The following code below achieved my cross server relay idea.

```
if(command === "test" ) {

const Detail = args.join(" ");
bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
guild.channels.cache.find(t => t.name == 'association').send(Detail);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have made a small error inside of your `forEach` loop. See, the c contains all the information about the channel (id, name, guild, etc..), so, if you wanted to find it, you would need to do the following :

```
// Inside the forEach loop
const ch = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === c.name);
if(ch) ch.send(announcement);
```

I've also added an `if` statement to prevent an error from popping up if the channel could not be found.

Hope this will help you :)